# if not exist OR if not exist - how to do it in batch

Tags: file, batch-file

I have two files file1.a and file2.a within a directory.
I'm writing a batch script to look if file1.a not exist OR if file2.a not exists OR if booth files not exist call "mycommand" .

I have tried something like this:

```
if not exist file1.a || if not exist file2.a || if not exist file1.a && file2.a call mycommand
```

It doesn't work. Any idea/suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse your logic and *skip* your command if both files exist:

```
if exist file1.a if exist file2.a goto :SKIP
call mycommand
:SKIP
```

You were misusing the `&&` and `||` operators which are conditional separators for commands, which makes the second one to execute depending on whether or not the first one succeeds (for instance, `copy source destin && echo SUCCESS || echo FAILURE`).

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to skip if either of the file is present so I would do it this way:

```
if exist file1.a goto skip
if exist file2.a goto skip
goto end
:SKIP
mycommand
:END
```